# Use vbscript to input data in Excel userform and proceed

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript, userform

Thank you in advance for considering my post.
I have an Excel file that contains a userform with a username and password field that appears everytime i open the Excel. Also, some of the worksheets are protected.
Being new to vbscripting, I wanted to know how I can use it to:

1. open the workbook in the background
2. input the username and password in the excel userform
3. click the submit button from the userform
4. run the refresh all macro found in Module1

So far I was able to open the workbook in the backgroung and test it without the userform but since I cannot enter the username and password, I am unable to proceed further.

```
Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 

oExcel.Visible = False
oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
oExcel.AskToUpdateLinks = False
oExcel.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False

Set oWorkbook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("filepath\file.xlsx")
oWorkbook.RefreshAll
oWorkbook.Save

Msgbox "Excel file has been refreshed", VBOKOnly

oExcel.Quit
Set oWorkbook = Nothing
Set oExcel = Nothing
```

Comment: The userform contains the following : UserName textbox, Password textbox, Submit and Cancel click buttons. I don't know how and where I should place the code so that I reads the above info when the script is run :(

Comment: Can you upload your Excel file ? And share its link ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***First :*** Your file has an extension with `.xlsm` and not `.xlsx` check this before proceeding !

***Second :*** You should add this instruction in the vbscript : `oWorkbook.Unprotect 1234` to unprotect the WorkBook (The password by default that i found is `1234` in your Excel file)

***Third :*** I added `On Error Resume Next` instruction to catch error if it occurs

---

```
Option Explicit
Dim Title,oExcel,oWorkbook
Title = "Use vbscript to input data in Excel userform and proceed"
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
oExcel.Visible = False
oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
oExcel.AskToUpdateLinks = False
oExcel.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False
On Error Resume Next
Set oWorkbook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Stack\Data.xlsm")
oWorkbook.Unprotect 1234 ' The password to unprotect the WorkBook is 1234
oWorkbook.RefreshAll
oWorkbook.Save
If Err Then
    MsgBox "Error Source : " & Err.Source & vbCrlf &_
    "Error Description : "& Err.Description,vbCritical,Title
Else
    Msgbox "Excel file has been refreshed",vbInformation,Title
End If
oExcel.Quit
Set oWorkbook = Nothing
Set oExcel = Nothing
```

Comment: Excellent answer.

Comment: Thank you @Hackoo. I will test the script and get back to you.